# IA32 indexed addressing mode without base address

Tags: assembly, addressing-mode

What does this syntax mean? I'm specifically unsure about the missing base address

```
mov    0x804a1d4(,%edx,4),%eax
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

assign the contents of `0x804a1d4 + %edx*4` to `%eax`

Comment: That is backwards. The contents of the address (0x804a1d4 + edx * 4) are assigned to eax.

Answer (score 1):

There is no base. Either the base register or the offset register (but not both) may be omitted. In this case the base address is hard-coded and the value to be moved into eax is loaded from

```
  0x804a1d4 + (edx * 4)
```